# problem with class considered like abstract class but whitout virtual pure method

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I have a problem with abstract classes.
I have declared two class **Valeur** (abstract class) and **Boolleen**

**Valeur.hh**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
namespace common {

class Valeur {
public:
    virtual bool operator==(Valeur const& v) const =0;
};
class Boolleen : public Valeur {
private:
    bool _b;
public:
    Boolleen (bool b);
    bool operator==(Valeur const& v);

};

}
```

**Valeur.cpp**

```
#include "valeur.h"
using namespace common;

Boolleen::Boolleen(bool b): Valeur(), _b(b) {}

bool Boolleen::operator==(Valeur const& v) {
    return true;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "valeur.h"
int main()
{
    common::Boolleen b(true); // DOESN'T WORK ???
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to instantiate the Boolleen class the compiler tells me it's an abstract class, yet I didn't declare a pure virtual method in Boolleen. **I would like to be able to build a Boolleen object without worry**

Comment: `virtual bool operator==(Valeur const& v) const =0;` has a `const` on the end. That makes it a different function from `bool operator==(Valeur const& v);` which does not have the same  `const`

Comment: virtual `operator==` is a bad design. In this example, you will compare `Boollean` to any object derived from Valeur and ignore everything beyond the base. Or, you need to know the full list of derived classes when you are programming `Boollean`.

Answer (score 3):

You didn’t implement `Boolleen::operator==(const Valeur &v) const`, and thus it’s an abstract class since one method is still pure virtual (the equality operator from Valeur). Pay close attention to the signature :)

To avoid such bugs in the future, anytime you intend to override a virtual method, put `override` after the declaration. That way the compiler will not let you compile the code if the overridden method has an incorrect signature.

Comment: @Monsieur AZERTY No problem. Sleep is necessary :)